# Umbraco Razor - binding content fields

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-mvc

I've created a template (View) in Umbraco (MVC) and am trying to figure out how to bind to the document type content. Keeping it really simple:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
```

My Umbraco document type has a Title field (alias is 'title') but if I try and run this I get build errors. I've found a whole load of documentation suggesting using a Library.NodeById() method but I believe that's for WebForms and not MVC. Can anyone offer some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a property value in multiple ways with Model::

```
@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("title")

@Model.Content.GetProperty("title").Value
```

And as a dynamic

```
@CurrentPage.Title
```

Did you remember to add your template to your document type?

Comment: Yes I did add a template to a document type - those are useful thanks. Out of curiosity do you know if you can make an MVC Model based on a Document Type for strongly typed binding?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I've never seen that before. Only if you make your own model and bind that to your view.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Field helper method:

```
@Umbraco.Field("myFieldName")
```

nice thing about this helper is that you can also specify alternative fields (if the first one was empty.

You can find this back in the documentation: 
http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/Mvc/views#RenderingafieldwithUmbracoHelper